# chmod +x gradlew ./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies --stacktrace fail

Tags: android, jenkins

I'm trying build android apk using:

```
jenkins@test-jenkins-vm:/home/lesha$ java --version

openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.2, mixed mode)
```

and

```
jenkins@test-jenkins-vm:/home/lesha$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.10.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-09-19 18:10:15 UTC
Revision:     b4d8d5d170bb4ba516e88d7fe5647e2323d791dd

Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-6
Kotlin:       1.2.61
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-1023-azure amd64
```

My android sdk located at

```
jenkins@test-jenkins-vm:/home/lesha$ cd $ANDROID_HOME
jenkins@test-jenkins-vm:/opt/android-sdk-linux$ ls
NOTICE.txt  bin      emulator    lib       mksdcard  platforms  source.properties  tools
android     build-tools  emulator-check  licenses  monitor   proguard   support
```

When I execute

```
chmod +x gradlew && ./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies --stacktrace
```

I get an error

> [Gradle] - Launching build.
>       [Android] $ gradle clean build clean build --refresh-dependencies --stacktrace -b build.gradle
>
> ```
> > Configure project :app
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 in /opt/android-sdk-linux/licenses
> License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 accepted.
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 (revision: 27.0.3)".
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 (revision: 27.0.3)" ready.
> Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 in /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/27.0.3
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 (revision: 27.0.3)" complete.
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3 (revision: 27.0.3)" finished.
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in /opt/android-sdk-linux/licenses
> License for package Android SDK Platform 27 accepted.
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 3)".
> "Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 3)" ready.
> Installing Android SDK Platform 27 in /opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-27
> "Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 3)" complete.
> "Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 3)" finished.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> > Failed to find target with hash string 'android-27' in: /opt/android-sdk-linux
> ```

Can anybody help?